# Error message not appearing even when imagebutton is empty

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am developing a simple app in Kotlin Android Studio. For validation purposes, I want to display an error message when the user submits a form without attaching an image via the imagebutton. Something like the type of message shown for `EditText.setError("Error")` but for ImageButton. I tried doing a toast but it's not showing.

Here are the relevant codes:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainactivity)

        ...

        val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
        imageButton.isEnabled = false

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 111)
        }
        else
        {
            imageButton.isEnabled = true

            imageButton.setOnClickListener {
                var intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
            }
        }

        val buttonSubmit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonSubmit)

        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener {

            submitART(userId.toString(), HRWAnswer, ResultAnswer)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode==101)
        {
            var picture = data?.getParcelableExtra<Bitmap>("data") // ? - it can be a null

            // add the image to the image button
            imageButton.setImageBitmap(picture)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == 111 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
            imageButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    fun submitART(userId : String, HRWOption: String, ResultOption: String){

        ...
        val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)

        ...
        if(imageButton.drawable==null){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Image of your ART result is required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an `android:src` attribute set on the `<ImageButton>` in the layout?

Comment: Just add findViewById only one time in code, Remove `val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)` from `submitART()`, `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, it creates multiple objects of imagebutton.